# Gradle 4.0 does not display executed tasks in command line

Tags: java, gradle, terminal

When I run `gradle build` or any other gradle command from terminal I can't see recently executed tasks and their status (for example `:testClasses UP-TO-DATE`), but only `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`:

[image: Behaviour in command line]

However everything is fine when I run build command from eclipse IDE using gradle plugin:

[image: Behaviour in Eclipse IDE]

I'm using Gradle 4.0. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Do you use -q ?
If try to use -info it write more information ?

Comment: @VasileBors -info solves the issue partly, however the output is kinda huge and not easy readable, I just want to see task hierarchy. I solved the issue, see my own answer below. Cheers.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I figured out the issue. If you execute `gradle --help-` you may notice the `--console` option in the options list which is responsible for output during gradle task execution. Since gradle v4.0 console option is set to *rich* by default which causes the output I get using terminal. Basically using `--console=plain` fixes the issue (for example: `gradle --console=plain build`).

Comment: I've searched for making it default, but could not find one.. Instead I use `alias` something like this: `alias gradle='gradle --console=verbose'`

Comment: `echo "alias gradle='gradle --console=verbose'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Instead of an alias you can set this, and other defaults, in a `gradle.properties` file in the either the project root (applying to just that project) or `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory (applying to all gradle commands). A properties file lets you set the default but still change via the command line if needed. Setting an alias means the console mode is fixed unless you redefine the alias. Add `org.gradle.console=...` to the properties file. See here for full docs on this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 12):

As of Gradle 4.3 there is another option: `--console=verbose`

This uses the new rich style output introduced in 4.0, but also outputs the task headers and outcomes (`:compileJava UP-TO-DATE` etc) that were the default in earlier versions. It also colors the output which `--console=plain` doesn't do.

The feature is detailed here in the release notes:
https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/release-notes.html#new-command-line-options

Full list of options:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_customizing_log_format