# How to remove > Task: progress logs from Gradle output

Tags: gradle, logging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-arctic-fox

Since I updated to Android Studio Arctic Fox, I started seeing a lot of gradle logs about the dependencies being run:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :buildSrc:generateExternalPluginSpecBuilders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:extractPrecompiledScriptPluginPlugins UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:generatePrecompiledScriptPluginAccessors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:generateScriptPluginAdapters UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileTestKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:pluginUnderTestMetadata UP-TO-DATE
...
```

The problem with this is that it is difficult for my team to immediately see exceptions because they would need to scroll to the bottom to see any them.

Is there a way to remove those logs? I tried with logger `quiet` and `warn` mode and I am still seeing the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior [is controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45883963/750510) by the `--console` option. Set it to `rich` (`./gradlew test --console=rich`) and Gradle will hide the tasks (to show them back use `--console=plain`). You could persist this setting in many ways. The simpliest one: add `org.gradle.console=rich` to your project's `gradle.properties`.

However, it's all about stand-alone terminal apps (Terminal on Mac, Konsole in Linux/KDE, etc). Android Studio's terminal may just not support it!

Comment: Yes as you mention, AS has other configuration and it doesn't work as expected