# Not print sequence of executed tasks

Tags: java, gradle

To create distributive of my java app I use this Gradle task:

```
gradle clean distZip
```

And here output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Ok, but I need to print sequences of all executed tasks. Smt like this:

```
app:clean
app:JavaCompile
app:jar
distZip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889966/17706960), using `--console` should solve your problem.

Like this: `gradle --console=plain clean distZip`